# Making multiple line plots on a map in R. Need separate line segments plotted rather than a continuous path

Tags: r, plot, line, ggmap

I am new to R and wanted to know how to make multiple line plots in a R map. I have two dataframes :

```
df1= Airport | Lat | Lon
     --------------------
     LAX     | 10  | -11
     SFO     | 20  |  45
     BOS     | 30  | -22

df2= Orig | Dest | Weight
     --------------------
     LAX  | BOS  | 2.3
     SFO  | BOS  |  1
     BOS  | JFK  | 6.1
```

Given these two dataframes, I want line plots on ggmaps that are from the origin airport to the destination airport with the given linewidth. I will be using ggmaps

```
usa <- get_map(location = "United States of America", zoom = 4)
ggmap(usa)
```

Comment: I did not find the answer in that link useful. The example mentioned there plotted a random dataset on the map using connected lines. The plot was a path and not discrete line segments.

Comment: You coordinates are incorrect e.g. LAX is (33.942791,-118.410042). Fix that before you want do draw something on the map.

Comment: On [my blog](https://www.symbolix.com.au/blog-main/2017-1) there is an example of doing this that may be of interest